# Алиасы/синонимы сайта

Tags: .htaccess

Стоит задача: имеется основной сайт [http://поддомен.домен.com](http://%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.com) 
необходимо чтобы по адресам типа:
[http://uno.поддомен.домен.com](http://uno.%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.com)
[http://duos.поддомен.домен.com](http://duos.%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.com)
[http://treis.поддомен.домен.com](http://treis.%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.com) и так далее ...
открывалось содержимое основного сайта [http://поддомен.домен.com](http://%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.com)  и соответственно все относительные ссылки вели бы пользователя по путешествию внутри подсайта, то есть зашли мы на [http://uno.поддомен.домен.com](http://uno.%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.com) в меню есть ссылка "/about.html", соответственно ссылка эта должна привести браузер на адрес [http://uno.поддомен.домен.com/about.html](http://uno.%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.com/about.html) с содержимым идентичным [http://поддомен.домен.com/about.html](http://%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.com/about.html)

Подразумевается использование htaccess для настройки перезаписи. поскольку речь о поддоменах н-цатого уровня стандартными средствами хостинга данную задачу решить не удается.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не до конца понятен. Попробую, впрочем, ответить. Пишем в .htaccess:

```
//Включаем модуль ReWriteEngine:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

// условие перенаправления
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^duos.поддомен.домен.com$ [NC]
// но оставляем старый адрес в браузере
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://поддомен.домен.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: В данном случае мы получили перенаправление на основной поддомен

Comment: мы в любом случае получим перенаправление, НО при добавлении флага [R=301,L] браузер перейдет на основной поддомен, а если использовать только флаг [L], то в строке браузера останется прежнее значение, а материалы будут взяты с основного поддомена

Comment: в том то и дело, что в строке браузера не остается прежнее значение